# Burning of Natural Gas

Tags: physical-chemistry

I would like to compare the burning of Natural gas to heat the external object 1) when Natural Gas gets fired with Pure Oxygen 2) when Natural gas gets fired with Atmospheric Air.

- What are the resultant products in the above two scenarios.
- Is there any difference of heating rate (of any external object, if the flame is directed on that external object)
- Which one is desirable between the two for achieving required temperature in given time and for achieving maximum combustion efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The combustion of any natural gas occurs by the same equation with air or with pure oxygen. It is $\ce{CH4 + 2 O2 -> CO2 + 2 H2O}$, The amount of heat produced by its combustion is the same with air and pure oxygen. But the final temperature its not the same, as the heat of combustion in air is partly used for heating an important amount of nitrogen. The same amount of heat has to heat $3$ gases with pure oxygen ($\ce{1 CO2 + 2 H2O}$), and $11$ gases with air $\ce{(1 CO2 + 2 H2O + 8 N2}$). So the increase of temperature is about three to four times higher with pure oxygen than with air.

Comment: Not counting the  small amount of nitrogen oxides that might be formed, depending on temperature and rate of reaction. See https://www3.epa.gov/ttnchie1/ap42/ch01/final/c01s04.pdf

Comment: Such estimate of temp. is just too crude and I wonder why you bother with such questions (rhetoric question).

Comment: Mithoron. Of course my estimate of temperature is crude. But I suspect  the author of the question is not interested in a rigorous calculation. He might just need a qualitative approach.